# python utf-8 encoding error in my computer

Tags: python, visual-studio, email, utf-8

I made a **mail verification application with python**. When I write the application codes in the [online python editor](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) and on another computer, it works properly and sends the code, but the visual studio installed on my computer gives an error and the error is like this;
Error!
**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 5: invalid start byte**

here is my code

> ```
> from smtplib import SMTP 
> import random 
> randomCode = random.randint(10000,99999)
> sendTo = "******@gmail.com" 
> try:
>    # Mail Message Information
>    subject = "E-Mail authentication system"
>    message = ("Here is E-Mail authentication system"+ " :" str(randomCode))
>    contents = "Subject: {0}\n\n{1}".format(subject,message)
>
>    # Account Information
>    mailaddress = "**********@gmail.com"
>    password = "password"
>
>    # To Whom To Send Information
>    mail = SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
>    mail.ehlo()
>    mail.starttls()
>    mail.login(mailaddress,password)
>    mail.sendmail(mailadress, sendTo, contents.encode("utf-8"))
>    print("Your code has been sent successfully!")
>    codeChecker = int(input("Please enter the code : "))
>    if codeChecker == randomCode:
>        print("You are succesfuly login.")
>        print("Login screen")
>    else:
>        print("The code you entered is incorrect please try again")
>
> except Exception as e:
> print("Error!\n {0}".format(e))
> ```

Comment: Your code is OK, but there are various hints that your have edited the code before posting it here. It is ok (and recommended) to edit code (e.g. to shorten it), but you should test it. Also if you copy exact the stack trace and you highlight the line which cause the problem (e.g. adding a comment) will help. I suspect that you modified some `print`, and the error is about your terminal not supporting UTF-8: very common error in Windows). If this is the error, you will find a lot of solution in this site.

Comment: determine if your file contains the UTF BOM code at the start, use an hex editor or byte dump tool

Comment: Bytes F8-FF never occur in UTF-8 encoding, so the bytes are not encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try to determine or recognise the encoding of the input string and decode it first in Unicode and then encode it as UTF-8, for example: `str.decode("cp1252").encode("utf-8")`.